# Android ndk log unicode (wide characters)

Tags: java, c++, unicode, android-ndk, logcat

I am trying to write to logcat unicode characters (UTF16; wide characters like Japanese, Korean or Chinese). The only success is a work around which is to send it to Java as a string (for example the code below):

```
unsigned short* text = new unsigned short[100];      // or jchar*
.... // all some unicode to the array
jstring jtext = jniEnv->NewString(text, (jsize)length);
jniEnv->CallVoidMethod( JavaClass, JavaPrintUnicode, jtext );
... // Clean up

// Then java prints it out
```

However if the bytes are in a char array, `__android_log_print` will print garbled text. Is there a method to print out the text within the NDK (C++) side?

Comment: Is using UTF-8 an option?

Comment: It is but harder for me to convert it.

Comment: Note that what your `JavaPrintUnicode()` method actually does under the hood, it converts your UTF-16 to UTF-8 for print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android NDK, as typical for Linux, uses 32 bits to represent wide chars, so if conversion to  UTF-32 is trivial, you can try this:

```
unsigned short text[100];
// fill text with UTF-16; make sure that all characters are 2 bytes long
long utf32[100];
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
  utf32[i] = text[i];

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "UTF-32", "%ls", utf32);
```

Comment: how can you handle unicode characters that span over multiple character points?

Comment: @RobotMess: if the input is not trivial UCS-16, you need consistent support of wide characters. I recommend [Crystax NDK](https://www.crystax.net/android/ndk) for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can print hex values for each character instead.

```
void print_string_as_hex(WCHAR* ws){
    int l = wcslen(ws);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < l ; i++) 
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "MyTag", "%x", ws[i]);
}
```

To get the encoded character from hex values, you can use Microsoft Word - `4513[Alt-x]` will encode `0x4513`for you.